# Is there an && equivalent in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

The title pretty much says it all. Having a function that could AND or OR statements would be useful in scheme rather than writing nested IFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`and`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=and#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/letstx-scheme..rkt%29._and%29%29) and [`or`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html?q=and#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/letstx-scheme..rkt%29._or%29%29). You don't specify which flavor of Scheme you're using, but I think those are standard macros. (Note that they're implemented as recursive macros—not functions—otherwise you couldn't get the desired short-circuiting behavior.)